# Cent OS unable to login after passwd

Tags: centos, root, passwd

I tried to change password of centos root using passwd command. But accidentally I pressed enter key without entering any password. Now I can't login to server, neither using old password nor without password. Is there any way around this without resetting password via grub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link to reset the password of `root` user

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/4022-reset-root-password-on-centos-5-6

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But I would like to find a way to access my server without resetting password from grub, I think it causes some problem on system.

Comment: Nothing will be effect to your files and other system setting with this. You will be able to login

Comment: While using desktop version of centos, after resetting password using grub there were some issues with graphics, I am afraid there might be other issues too so I don't want to reset it on production server. But I think there isn't a way around other than grub reset.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately only reset the password if you do not have another account with configured sudo.

Comment: Thats it. I don't have another account with sudo, so I will go with grub reset. Thanks BTW.